# Script is set to trigger on edit does not seem to be triggering - any ideas?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the below script that was written to archive a row of data once column 14 has been edited. This is a shared 'status page', used within our company to collaborate on shipment statuses. For some reason the script will not trigger on edit of any column and I can't figure out why. I use this exact same script in a few other google sheets and it works fine, but for some reason won't work here.

```
function onEdit(e) {
let originalSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Current');
let originalName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetName();
let copy = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Shipped');

  //checking if the right column is changed AND it's the right spreadsheet AND that the header column is   NOT     changed
  if (e.range.getColumn() === 14.0 && originalName === "Current" && e.range.getRow() !== 1){

  //getting range to copy (i.e. the row with 5 cells of data)
  let rangeToCopy = originalSheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 1, 1, 14);


  var rowLast = copy.getLastRow();
  copy.insertRowAfter(rowLast); 

  rangeToCopy.copyTo(copy.getRange(copy.getLastRow() + 1, 1));

  //delete row
  e.source.deleteRow(e.range.getRow()); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you check the execution log for error in `onEdit`?

Comment: @TheWizEd here's the error log - I was under the impression that this error would show because it hadn't been triggered, am I thinking about that correctly?

    Error 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')
onEdit @ Untitled.gs:7

Comment: No, for what ever reason the event object `e` does not have a `range` property.  Try this right after `function onEdit(e) {` put `Logger.log(e);`.

Answer (score 0):

It will run a little faster if you were to write it like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let sh = e.source.getSheetByName('Current');
  let name = sh.getName();
  let copy = e.source.getSheetByName('Shipped');
  if (e.range.columnStart == 14 && name === "Current" && e.range.rowStart != 1) {
    let rangeToCopy = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 14);
    copy.insertRowAfter(copy.getLastRow());
    rangeToCopy.copyTo(copy.getRange(copy.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
    e.source.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```